# Cordova AngularJs app is not working in iod Wkwebview while it is working in UIWebview

Tags: angularjs, cordova, wkwebview

I have done the following steps:

1. Uninstall all the plugins (whitelist, device, dialogs, inappbroweser, network information, statysbar, splashscreen, tts, file)
2. Remove the ios platform
3. Add the ios platform
4. Install all the above plugins again to update them
5. Install a new plugin cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine
6. Add following kines in config.xml file for ios:

```
<feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
  <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
</feature>

<preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
```

If I comment ui-view div then index.html page showing but uncommenting that line shows blank white screen.

Please help me to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem when using WKWebView with AngularJS since WKWebView raises an exception when trying to load local files. Since you already have the latest version for your plugins add the following plugin and everything should be working again!

https://github.com/TheMattRay/cordova-plugin-wkwebviewxhrfix